# How do I eliminate render blocking JavaScript and CSS in above fold content

Tags: javascript, css, render-blocking

I am trying to improve my Google Page Insight score and it states that I need to do the following;

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>
> Your page has 1 blocking script resources and 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>
> None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
>
> Remove render-blocking JavaScript

`http://gbnet.giggleberries.netdna-cdn.com/…a/js/aeb20058a8567ed3acc857b2edcd8af2.js`

> Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

`http://gbnet.giggleberries.netdna-cdn.com/…css/d497d831cf1abb3dbc3960b0f3e9bcf7.css
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin`

Can anyone advise how I do this? Everything I look for on the internet refers to HTML sites and I have been informed that these solutions do not apply to a php site.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

When you run your site change the setting so css and js are merged/minified. Besides that you cannot without a serious rewriting of Magento which would make it pointless for you.

http://www.metacdn.com/speed-up-magento/combine-and-minify-js-css

http://inchoo.net/magento/merging-javascript-in-magento/